# pyspark time difference between events

Tags: python, apache-spark, datetime, pyspark

I have gigabytes of log data.
It has following columns:

- TimeStamp
- Parameter ID
- Paramteter Value

Now I have different questions i want to answer:

1. Downtime of the machine due to error number
   in "normal" python i would solve this like this:

```
// pseudocode not executable
error_and_downtime = {}
// there are 2000 possible errornumbers
for i in range(2000):
  error_and_downtime[i] = []

for i,row in enumerate(df):
  if row == error:
    for j in range(i, len(df))
      if df[j] == machine runs again:
        error_and_downtime[error_number].append(time_stamp_machine_runs - time_stamp_machine_error)
        break
```

In this way i will get a dictionary with all downtimes per error.

Due to the big amount of data, i will solve this with pyspark. But i have no idea how.
I know RDD, SQL, mapReduce a bit, but all seams not able to do this...

I hope someone can give me an approach that I can follow up. Thank you very much.

EDIT:
The data looks like this:

| Event | TimeStamp | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| s | 27.09.2022 17:24 | 245 |
| Error | 27.09.2022 17:24 | 245 |
| a | 27.09.2022 17:29 | -1522004285 |
| s | 27.09.2022 17:29 | 0.38 |
| d | 27.09.2022 17:29 | 0.38 |
| f | 27.09.2022 17:29 | 35.148 |
| State | 27.09.2022 17:29 | 6 |
| State | 27.09.2022 17:29 | 10 |
| s | 27.09.2022 17:29 | 0.38 |
| Error | 27.09.2022 17:40 | 300 |
| f | 27.09.2022 17:29 | 35.148 |
| State | 27.09.2022 17:29 | 6 |

After every error comes the State = 6 and the time between is the information of interest. In the value column is the error number given. I need the time duration after every error sorted by errortype. I ll update the table above. The goal is a list of durations for every errornumber. The State row can also have other numbers in value column, but only 6 means machine is running. I'd like to have every duration between Error and State = 6 in a list/dictonary for every error number. I hope it is understandable like this. Thanks for your help.

The data is given in lots of CSV files. I read the data and saved it as a parquet file.

EDIT2:
I think I have not yet formulated the question correctly.
The column "Event" can contain various parameters. Also the entry "State" in the column "Event" can occur several times, much more than the entry "Error". I am interested in the time differences between "Event = Error" with "Value > 0" and the next "Event = State" with "Value = 6". Since "Event = Error" contains the error number in the "Value", I would like to have a list/dictonary/dataframe in which the downtimes are stored for each error number. I also noticed that my conversion to the format "timestamp" was still incorrect, I have lost the seconds and milliseconds. I have corrected this now:
Row(timestamp=datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 2, 2, 33, 17, 73900))

The goal of the whole action is in a first step to find out the downtime of the machine in dependence of the stop triggering error.

Comment: unfortunately your question is somewhat vague. what does your log data look like and how are you accessing it in `pyspark`? if you can show us a small sample of your logs (or even just made up logs similar to yours), that would be helpful.

Comment: I added a short sequence of the data as a table. Thank you.

Comment: please explain what you are trying to actually achieve ? what result are you seeking ?  ... how to ask a good question:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I updated my post again. I have now some negative durations. how can this happen?

Answer (score 0):

If this data can be loaded into a pyspark dataframe, we could convert the `TimeStamp` column into a new column of `TimestampType` (so that we can take the difference between timestamps later), use a [window partition](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-window-functions/) to create a new column called `"Event_count"` for the cumulative count of error and state events (under the assumption that there is exactly one error event for every state event), then perform a groupby on `Event_count` and take the difference between min and max timestamps in this group.

For example, I'll create a pyspark DataFrame with information similar to yours (omitting the `Values` column because we only need type of event and timestamp):

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("Error", "27.09.2022 17:24"),
        ("a", "27.09.2022 17:29"),
        ("State", "27.09.2022 17:29"),
        ("Error", "28.09.2022 00:00"),
        ("a", "27.10.2022 00:10"),
        ("State", "28.09.2022 00:10"),
        ("Error", "29.09.2022 00:09"),
        ("a", "28.09.2022 00:10"),
        ("State", "29.09.2022 00:10"),
    ],
    ["Event", "Timestamp"]
)
```

which looks like the following:

```
+-----+----------------+
|Event|       Timestamp|
+-----+----------------+
|Error|27.09.2022 17:24|
|    a|27.09.2022 17:29|
|State|27.09.2022 17:29|
|Error|28.09.2022 00:00|
|    a|27.10.2022 00:10|
|State|28.09.2022 00:10|
|Error|29.09.2022 00:09|
|    a|28.09.2022 00:10|
|State|29.09.2022 00:10|
+-----+----------------+
```

Then we can create our window partition and run a chain of operations to extract what we need:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df = df.withColumn("Timestamp_new", F.to_timestamp(F.col("Timestamp"), 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm'))
windowEventCount = Window.partitionBy("Event").orderBy("Timestamp_new")
durations = df.filter(
    F.col("Event").isin("Error","State")
).withColumn(
    "Event_number",F.row_number().over(windowEventCount)
).groupby(
    "Event_number"
).agg(
    F.min("Timestamp_new").alias("Error_timestamp"),
    (F.minute(F.max("Timestamp_new")) - F.minute(F.min("Timestamp_new")) ).alias("Duration_in_minutes")
).sort(
    'event_number'
)

# display the resulting pyspark dataframe
durations.show()
```

Result:

```
+------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|Event_number|    Error_timestamp|Duration_in_minutes|
+------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|           1|2022-09-27 17:24:00|                  5|
|           2|2022-09-28 00:00:00|                 10|
|           3|2022-09-29 00:09:00|                  1|
+------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: hank you for your answer. I am not able to run the code. How is F defined? 
I updated description again. I hope it is clear now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You need some imports from pyspark. I've updated my answer

Comment: @dach did this answer end up working for you?